# Characteristic polynomial of endomorphism $F\colon M(n\times n,K)\to M(n\times n,K)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I have the following exercise, which isn't a homework, because i quit university a few month ago and my course about linear algebra was in 2011. The question is at the end of my demonstration.

> Let $K$ be a field, $A\in M(n\times n,K)$ be fixed, $P_A$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and $F\colon M(n\times n,K)\to M(n\times n,K)$ an endomorphism given by $F(B)=A\cdot B$.
>
> Show that the characteristic polynomial $P_F$ of $F$ is given by $P_F=(P_A)^n$.

**Attempt**: The case $n=1$ is trivial, so I proved the theorem for $n=2$ to see what happens in the general case in the following way: Define
\begin{align*}
E_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}\, i=j\\
0 & \text{if}\, i\neq j
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then $\mathcal{E}=\lbrace E_{11},E_{21},E_{12},E_{22}\rbrace$ is a basis of $M(2\times 2,K)$ and the function $F$ is represented by the matrix
\begin{align*}
S=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & 0 & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{11} & a_{12} \\
0 & 0 & a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
with respect to the basis $\mathcal{E}$. The characteristic polynomial of $S$ is equal the characteristic polynomial of $F$, thus $P_F=P_S=(P_A)^2$ because $S$ is a block matrix with $A$ on the diagonal. I think this proof can be generalized  in that way: For all $n\geq 1$ the function $F$ will be represented by a diagonal block matrix $S\in M(n^2\times n^2,K)$ with $A$ on the diagonal by the same arguments as above, hence $P_F=P_S=(P_A)^n$.

**Question:** Is it correct and is there an alternative or better and smart way to prove it? Mathematical induction? I didn't use it, i used a good portion intuition!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good and works, it's just shy in the spirit. I would suggest another approach.

Consider the following linear map $$\downharpoonleft_k : \mathbb{K}^n \longrightarrow \text{M}(n,\mathbb{K})$$  $$v \mapsto  \begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
 &  & & &  \\
0 & \dots & v  & \dots & 0 \\
 &  &  &  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
 $$ 
where $v$ is precisely in the  $k$th column.

Clearly $$F(\downharpoonleft_k v) = \lambda \downharpoonleft_kv$$ as soon as $v$ in an eivenvector for $\lambda$.

Now your turn.

Comment: $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$? Why don't you give the map $\mathbb{K}^n\to \mathrm{M}(n,\mathbb{K})$ a name like $\phi$ or something else?

Comment: Yes, of $A$. Names are not relevant, I like the harpoon.

Comment: I arrived at the last equation. Let $\phi_k$ be this map, then $F(\phi_k(v))=\lambda \phi_k(v)$ is ok for me. But what does it prove?

Comment: Ok, I wanted to give you an hint. If you now take a basis $\mathcal{B}$ such that $A$ is triangular in this basis, how does $F$ look like in the basis $\{\downharpoonleft_k \mathcal{B}\}_{k \leq n}$?

Comment: Is it diagonal?

Comment: No, it has n blocks, in each blog it looks the same of $A$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: And the blocks are on the diagonal! Am i right?

Comment: Oh, yes, there they are.

Comment: I got it, thank you for your help!